# Are there LaTeX packages able to plot Grace language files?

Tags: packages, graphs

**EDIT** The below output file *as identified below in the comments (thank you)* is in the `Grace` language for plotting.

I was wondering if there are any packages capable of using the Grace language to include graphs in LaTeX rather than the standard .eps or .png etc.

```
@version 50109
@default linewidth 1.5
@g0 on
@with g0
@    world xmin      0.00
@    world xmax    754.92
@    world ymin     -0.25
@    world ymax      2.50
@    view xmin 0.150000
@    view xmax 0.602214
@    view ymin 0.150000
@    view ymax 0.850000
@    xaxis  bar linewidth 1.5
@    xaxis  tick major linewidth 1.5
@    xaxis  tick minor linewidth 1.5
@    xaxis  tick major  136
@    xaxis  label "Cutoff energy (EV)"
@    yaxis  bar linewidth 1.5
@    yaxis  tick major linewidth 1.5
@    yaxis  tick minor linewidth 1.5
@    yaxis  tick major    1.0000
@    yaxis  label "Energy error (EV/atom)"
@g1 on
@with g1
@    world xmin      0.00
@    world xmax    754.92
@    world ymin     -4.00
@    world ymax      1.00
@    view xmin 0.717657
@    view xmax 1.169872
@    view ymin 0.150000
@    view ymax 0.850000
@    xaxis  tick major  136
@    xaxis  label "Cutoff energy (EV)"
@    yaxis  label "Log10 |Energy error| (EV/atom)"
@target G0.S0
@type xy
   53.9491654150072        16.5784258405490     
   108.459781227830        1.37706700787840     
   162.989051467077       3.431021246137789E-002
   216.282381168537       1.945370131102209E-002
   264.211994723891       7.044388309623173E-003
   316.934569634781       1.883579609511798E-003
   374.450105901206       1.072583647783176E-003
   420.610728941616       7.798143890340725E-004
   486.513947975269       5.595554691808502E-004
   539.208152497737       3.921376373909879E-004
   594.355578932754       2.913218597768719E-004
   652.441864522262       1.875952541467996E-004
   692.582915874872       1.474738464821712E-004
   754.919784783225       1.057575141203415E-004
&
@target G0.S1
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000   2.00000000000000     
   754.919784783225        2.00000000000000     
&
@target G0.S2
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  0.300000000000000     
   754.919784783225       0.300000000000000     
&
@target G0.S3
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  0.100000000000000     
   754.919784783225       0.100000000000000     
&
@target G0.S4
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  1.000000000000000E-002
   754.919784783225       1.000000000000000E-002
&
@target G1.S0
@type xy
   53.9491654150072        1.21954329091756     
   108.459781227830       0.138955073476815     
   162.989051467077       -1.46457659262531     
   216.282381168537       -1.71099775649645     
   264.211994723891       -2.15215671231883     
   316.934569634781       -2.72501601961201     
   374.450105901206       -2.96956882841683     
   420.610728941616       -3.10800875552859     
   486.513947975269       -3.25215685504253     
   539.208152497737       -3.40656147209213     
   594.355578932754       -3.53562692620556     
   652.441864522262       -3.72677815275828     
   692.582915874872       -3.83128499213042     
   754.919784783225       -3.97568876603266     
&
@target G1.S1
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  0.301029995663981     
   754.919784783225       0.301029995663981     
&
@target G1.S2
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000 -0.522878745280338     
   754.919784783225      -0.522878745280338     
&
@target G1.S3
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  -1.00000000000000     
   754.919784783225       -1.00000000000000     
&
@target G1.S4
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  -2.00000000000000     
   754.919784783225       -2.00000000000000     
&
```

Comment: The language is [Grace](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/) I think... as for LaTeX packages - no idea! :-)

Comment: As long as you have an output with coordinates, you can always build a script in a language (say C++, Python) that scans and transform it in what you like the most. For my master thesis I converted locations of bus stops of Torino Transportation system available in a script into a very nice [TikZ picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o4edvmwfjd7phn6/rel-map.png) (see the beauty of Jake's zoomboxes ;) ).

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I didn't realise Grace had its own plotter language, the clue that Grace did read them should have been a clue! @ClaudioFiandrino la tua mappa e' molto bella! I don't think I will bother doing so, it was a convenient idea in case I may need to include these plots in vector HD, otherwise I will use .png and forget about it :).